# Pytest with sqlalchemy db conection terminates in subsequent test case

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest

I am using a sqlalchemy engine connection as a pytest fixture as a way to test functions that require database interaction. When I run the test cases individually by running `pytest tests/filename.py::test_get_token_data` or `pytest tests/filename.py::test_create` the test passes; however, when running the entire test case, `pytest tests/filename.py`, I get the following error:

```
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.errors.AdminShutdown) terminating connection due to administrator command
E       server closed the connection unexpectedly
E               This probably means the server terminated abnormally
E               before or while processing the request.
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

To my understanding, after each test, the database is suppose to be cleared (which I've confirmed), however, I do not understand the error. My code below.

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture
def db_connection(test_config, admin_db_connection):
    config = test_config()
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(config.DB_URL)
    connection = engine.connect()
    yield connection
    connection.close()

    # clear database
    from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs  # handle SQL quoting

    with admin_db_connection.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute("drop database %s with (force);", (AsIs(config.DB_NAME),))
        curs.execute(
            "create database %s template vtag_template;", (AsIs(config.DB_NAME),)
        )
```

**filename.py**

```
import sqlalchemy as sa


@pytest.fixture
def db_injection(db_connection):
    with db_connection.begin():
        some_value = db_connection.execute(
            sa.sql.text(
                """insert into general.some_table as t (some_id, name, description, is_active) values (:some_id, :name, :description, :is_active) returning t.some_id;

                """
            ),
            tenant_id='1234',
            description="TEST",
            is_active=True,
            name="TEST",
        )
        tenant_id_ = some_value.first()[0]
         
                
@pytest.fixture
def some_function(db_connection):

    with db_connection.begin():
        some_table = db_connection.execute(
            sa.sql.text(
                """
                SELECT e.name
                FROM general.some_table e
                WHERE e.id = 1234
            """
            )
        )
    return some_table.first()


def test_get_token_data(client, headers_with_token, db_injection, some_function):

    token = some_function.name
    #API is using the same db connection 
    response = client.get(f"/api/v2/{token}", headers=headers_with_token)

    assert response.status_code == 200


def test_create(client, img, b_64, headers_with_token, db_injection):

    items = Items(
        user_id=1234,
        template_id=67,
        b_64=b_64,
    )

    data = {
        "json": json.dumps(asdict(items)),
        "file": ("some_name", img, "multipart/form-data"),
    }

    response = client.post(
        "/api/v2/create",
        data=data,
        follow_redirects=True,
        content_type="multipart/form-data",
        headers=headers_with_token
    )

    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: In my case, I fixed similar issue by adding `poolclass=NullPool` argument to engine constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the application having an unbinded [Session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) being used. Since most of our application us using sqlalchemy's [Engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) API, we decide with refactor in using raw sql via `with engine.begin()`. Another alternative solution could have been adding the `engine` [into the session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#adding-additional-configuration-to-an-existing-sessionmaker)